# Dynamic Programming: Bits Array Java

Tags: java, algorithm, memory, matrix, dynamic-programming

I need to solve a `Dynamic Programming` problem for which I need to create a `N*N` size matrix in the memory. If I do create a matrix of `byte[][]` with size `N = 100000;` then it throws `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space` error.

In this matrix I will store either 0 or 1 at particular `ith` and `jth` index. So my use is limited to a bit only and I need a way so that I can just use only 1 bit size per matrix cell rather than over flooding memory keeping 8 bits in a cell where the need is only for 1 bit.

How can I achieve this?

Please take a note that my concern is not increasing heap of JVM, I am just searching for a way to optimally achieve the solution of a Dynamic Problem.

Comment: State the problem itself.

Comment: For most DP algorithms, you don't need to store the **entire** grid, just the last row or so.

Comment: Just the last row? 

but what if you need to go back to check for previous results?

Comment: For some problems it's certainly not possible to do this, and if you want the actual solution rather than the numeric value, you'll probably need the whole grid. It's just something to keep in mind. (Since you didn't specify the actual problem, we can't tell you whether or not it's possible).

Answer (score 2):

**Update**: I just checked and unfortuately, forget about the `BitSet`.

The genious API of `BitSet` is built on `int` indices. The integer range is out of your range for `N * N`. You therefore need to implement something by yourself. A suggestion:

```
public class BetterBitSet {

  private final long[] values;

  public BetterBitSet(int dimension) {
    values = new long[(int) ((long) dimension) * dimension / 8 / 64 + 1];
  }

  public void set(int i, int j, boolean value) {
    long index = index(i, j);
    int arrayIndex = arrayIndex(index);
    if (value) {
        values[arrayIndex] = set(values[arrayIndex], offset(index));
    } else {
        values[arrayIndex] = unset(values[arrayIndex], offset(index));
    }
  }

  public boolean isSet(int i, int j) {
    long index = index(i, j);
    return isSet(values[arrayIndex(index)], offset(index));
  }

  private boolean isSet(long value, int bitIndex) {
    return (value & (1L << bitIndex)) != 0;
  }

  private long set(long value, int bitIndex) {
    return value | (1L << bitIndex);
  }

  private long unset(long value, int bitIndex) {
    return value & ~(1L << bitIndex);
  }

  private long index(int i, int j) {
    return j * 8L + i;
  }

  private int arrayIndex(long index) {
    return (int) index / 64;
  }

  private int offset(long index) {
    return (int) index % 64;
  }
}
```

In doubt, have a look at `BitSet`'s source code and try something similar.

**Old answer**: The problem is that each index of `byte[][]` requires already 8 bit where you only store information about 1 bit. This requires already 9,536 MB for allocating this array on the heap so you run out of space. This amount of memory is most likely too much for your machine. With storing bits, you would however still require 1,192 MB. (Not taking into account any overhead caused by `BitSet`.) This is still a high number so make sure that your machine offers so much space which you must additionally assign to your JVM instance.

Comment: I'm pretty sure your calculation is off by a factor of 8. 10000000000 bits = 1250000000 bytes = 1220703 KB = 1192 MB

Comment: SO I need to find some other way to solve rather than using a matrix to hold 0 or 1 for a cell?

Comment: You can use a matrix with a bitset, just remember that if you have 4 elements in a row then the 5th bit must be on the second row.

Comment: True, I miscalculated. So unused to calculate with bit instead of byte.

Comment: With your explanation I have known one thing, giving it a thought of solving with bit array is not going to work because of memory problem. Because it still exhausts the limit.

Comment: raphw - Let me try it if your answer serves the purpose. I appreciate your concern.

Answer (score 1):

Java provides a managed bit-based data structure called a [`BitSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html). I say this is managed because Java does not have a native type for storing bits, instead, a `BitSet` stores individual bits as a component of a `long`, and keeps a `long[]` to back the set. This is a pretty storage-efficient approach, but the [implementation of `BitSet`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/util/BitSet.java#BitSet) reserves 6 bits out of every 64 for "addressing", which amounts to a 10% overhead just in the raw storage layer.

This means you can likely beat `BitSet` on storage by keeping and carefully addressing your own `long[]`, at the cost of some complexity and risk in your code. Unless you're extremely constrained on space, it's probably not worth saving the ~10% raw overhead of a `BitSet`.

It's probably also worth nothing that both of the solutions described above are single-dimensional arrays of bits. You can easily convert a two dimensional array to a one dimensional array by treating the one dimensional array as the concatenation of rows (at least, in this case you seem to assume equal row-widths). Addressing a specific cell in the matrix is simply:

```
row * (row_width) + column
```

Comment: Thank you for explanation.

with your explanation I have known one thing, giving it a thought of solving with bit array is not going to work because of memory problem. Because it still exhausts the limit.

Comment: You ran in the same trap as me. `BitSet` is limited by the range of integers in Java...

Answer (score 0):

In many cases you do not need all the sub problems for evaluating the current problem so i would advice the recursive top down solution to the DP problem with hashmap for storing the solution. Once a subproblem has been used you can remove it from hashmap to prevent overflow.
There is sometimes a slight performance penalty but would prevent memory full error.

[Memoization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization)

Comment: Vikram dost...main jo problem solve kar rha hoon...usme main HashMap use nhi kar sakta. With all the discussion above, one thing is confirm that I need to use Tree structure which will explore to a certain leave and then return back if solution is not found on the leaf's path. WHich will also help me to free the memory by freeing up the Node's memory from where tree returns.

Comment: @MasterJ Why cant u use it , u are using JVM right. Agar nahi to please tell your problem so that we can give a better optimization.

Comment: Most of the Dynamic Programming problems either make use of Matrix or Tree structures to evaluate a problem and to avoid recurring solutions.

HashMap is suitable for the problems like when I am going to find the factorial of a large number. Lets say 50, then I can store 50 to 0 factorial values in a hashmap. And next time when someone will ask for 52 I will just use 52*51*hashMap.get(50), which would return result quickly without making any calculation from 50, 49, 48....3,2,1, and 0! again.

Comment: @MasterJ U can use hashmap for any DP problem as u need to solve any encountered sub problem atleast once even using matrix so recursive solution can do it as efficiently by storing a solution for sub problem once found then use it in O(1). Moreover you donot need to solve subproblems which are not encountered in recursion which is not avoided in matrix based solution. This saves memory.

Comment: As you suggested, I have used Memoization technique. Factorial finding example that I gave was using the same technique. But every technique has its limitations. I do not need to store a value for a single Key but I do need to keep track for the whole diagonal of a matrix with index based accesses of its cell's values.

Comment: @MasterJ can i have your DP recurrence equation so that i can ponder on it because its not clear what u r trying to do here.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42427/discussion-between-masterj-and-vikram-bhat)